Fundamental group of cyclic branched cover of affine plane
Let $f\in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be an irreducible polynomial. Let $n>0$ be an integer such that the hypersurface $S:=\{ (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{C}^3|z^n=f(x,y) \}$ is  a connected complex submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^3$. Then $S\to \mathbb{C}^2, (x,y,z)\mapsto (x,y)$ is a cyclic branched cover of degree $n$. Zariski's work On the irregularity of cyclic multiple planes studies the first Betti number of smooth completions of $S$. But can we compute the first Betti number of $S$, or its fundamental group?

The irregularity is half the first Betti number, so at least part of your question can be answered. Zariski and van Kampen gave an algorithm to compute a presentation of the fundamental group of the complement of the branch curve (with explicit meridians) and that can be used to compute a presentation the fundamental group of cyclic covers. It's not very easy to use in practice, I find.

In generic cases, however, we understand everything, and $\pi_1$ is always trivial if the branch curve is non-singular and transverse to the line at infinity. (The latter assumption might not be necessary, but I'm throwing it out there for caution.)

Dear Professor @MarcoGolla, Would you mind giving me a reference for the statement "In generic cases, $\pi_1$ is always trivial"? Personally, I think Zariski proves that generically, the smooth completions of $S$ are simply connected.

I don't have a reference. The argument I had in mind is that $\pi_1$ of the complement of the branch curve is infinite cyclic (it's Abelian since the projective curve is nodal, and $H_1$ is easy to compute) and generated by the meridian of the higher-degree curve. All covers of the complement have $\pi_1 = \mathbb{Z}$, and when you glue in the branching locus upstairs you kill $\pi_1$.

Dear @MarcoGolla, Thanks!
